# Assembly code always result in segmentation Fault?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I'm starting to learn x86 assembly and tried to write a piece of code that will take input as i/o redirection and write it back as uppercase letters by i/o redirection to a file, but it seems to always cause segmentation fault although I tried to End it by a an exit system call and No output is written to the file.

```
READ: mov eax, 3        ; choose sys_read
          mov ebx, 0        ; file descriptor stdin 
          mov ecx, Buffer       ; pass address of buffer
          mov edx, BUFFER_LENGTH    ; set buffer length 
          int 80h           ; call read()
          cmp eax, 0        ; check if there is error reading
          jb EXIT           ; if -1 exit
          je EXIT           ; if  0 exit
    
    mov esi, eax            ; safe keeping number of bytes_read
    dec esi         ; adjust offset
    mov ebp, Buffer     ; Store address of Buffer in ebp
    add ebp, esi            ; ebp Now point to it's buffer end
    
        ; Now Start The Loop and Change Characters Needed

    LOOP: cmp byte[ebp], 61h    ; Check if it's equal to 'a'
          jb NEXT           ; GO to Next Character 
          cmp byte[ebp], 7Ah    ; Check if it's equal to 'z'
          ja NEXT           ; Go to next Character
          
          sub byte[ebp], 20h    ; ELSE convert to uppercase then go to next automatically
                 
     NEXT: dec esi          ; Decrement esi 'Counter'
           dec ebp          ; Decryment ebp "to point to previous Character"
           jnz LOOP     ; Go To the loop again to check Next Character until ZERO
           
           ; Once Reached Zero The ZF flag is set and write complete as Normal

    WRITE: mov edx, eax ; pass how many bytes to be written
           mov eax, 4   ; specify sys_write call
           mov ebx, 1   ; specify file descriptor
           mov ecx, Buffer  ; pass buffer address "changed letter"
           int 80h      ; make write call
           jmp READ ; Go to read again to read NEXT Chunk
           
     EXIT: mov eax, 1   ; specify sys_exit
           mov ebx, 0   ; specify return value
               int 80h      ; make sys_exit call
```

Comment: Where does the fault occur? (If you haven't already, use a debugger to find out.)

Comment: `ebp` holds a pointer into `Buffer`. It won't reach zero (Zero Flag = 1 after `dec ebp`) unless the buffer starts exactly at address 1, which is almost entirely impossible to happen. You should put `dec esi` immediately before the `jnz`. Even so, if `eax` starts out as 1 then your logic will fail. (You do detect `eax` equal to 0 in the prior handling.) And if `eax` starts at 2 you will only process 1 byte, not 2. Besides, you're not showing us where you declared `Buffer`.

Comment: @ecom actually this was the error a lot I swapped just these 2 lines and everything worked fine, Buffer was just stored in ```bss``` section. Thank's alot.

Comment: Your logic errors are not all fixed by swapping these instructions.

Comment: @ecm is this logic error caused by decrementing esi when it's zero so ```jnz``` will not fire since ```esi``` is now in negative and ```ZF``` is not set and next time ```LOOP``` runs it's off by one checking a location not in the buffer ?

Comment: @Khaled Gaber: Correct, that is one of the logic errors. This occurs when you get an `eax` = 1 return from the system call. As `esi` wraps around to negative numbers (or in unsigned terms, very large positive numbers) your loop will continue far past the size of your buffer. As you handle the buffer from the back to the front, this is an underflow. The other error is that you process one byte less than you should. Both errors are fixed by decrementing `ebp` after adding `esi` to it. `esi` should retain the original value of `eax`. Then `ebp` -> last byte of the buffer, `esi` = length in bytes.